# flink assign uid to window function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

is there a way to assign uid to a window function (such as apply(ApplyCustomFunction)) as we do for map/flatmap (or other) functions in Flink. The Flink version is 1.13.1.

I would like to specify the case with an example

```
DataStream<RECORD> outputDataStream = dataStream
                .coGroup(otherDataStream)
                .where(DATA::getKey)
                .equalTo(OTHERDATA::getKey)
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2)))
                .apply(new CoGroupFunction());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`CoGroupedStreams.WithWindow#apply(CoGroupFunction<T1,T2,T>)` doesn't have the return type that's needed for setting a UID or per-operator parallelism (among other things). This was done in order to keep binary backwards compatibility, and can't be fixed before Flink 2.0.

You can work around this by using the (deprecated) `with` method instead of `apply`, as in

```java
DataStream<RECORD> outputDataStream = dataStream
                .coGroup(otherDataStream)
                .where(DATA::getKey)
                .equalTo(OTHERDATA::getKey)
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2)))
                .with(new CoGroupFunction())
                .uid("window");
```

The `with` method will be removed once it is no longer needed.

Comment: I have to to use `apply` since I have CoGroupedStream (which does not allow `process`), in this case I cannot put .uid after apply, it cannot be found as method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `with()` instead of `apply()`. It will be fixed in 2.0 version, how it sayed in documentation